# Hibernate - How to map two tables on two columns?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `framework_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fileName` varchar(777) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fileSize` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `filePath` varchar(777) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fileUrl` varchar(777) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkedObjectID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkedObjectName` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `uploadDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `uploadersIP` varchar(77) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uploadersIPXFORWARDEDFOR` varchar(77) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(777) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `q_idx` (`linkedObjectID`,`linkedObjectName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=110 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And second table

```
CREATE TABLE `publicSitePortfolioWorks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mainName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tableName` varchar(250) DEFAULT 'publicSitePortfolioWorks',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to map publicSitePortfolioWorks to framework_files on `framework_files.linkedObjectID=publicSitePortfolioWorks.id and framework_files.linkedObjectName=publicSitePortfolioWork.tableName` .

I.e. publicSitePortfolioWorks have many objects of framework_files. All child objects must be in Set, like

```
private Set<FrameworkFiles> fileTEST = new HashSet<>(0);
```

How to map this Set in hbm.xml file? At this moment no foreign key between these two tables.

Comment: Please add foreign key between two tables and then map the set in HBM file

Comment: Is it possible to realize this without FK?

Comment: Think in SQL. Can you join this two tables without a link field? No, the same is with Hql

Comment: It's possible to link two tables with columns names from first and second tables without FK. For example firstTable.sid=secondTable.id. Is it possible to do it in Hibernate?

Comment: Yes. that's a logical FK (not physical). So you have resolved your issue.

Comment: OK. Can you provide a piece of code for Set's XML mapping code for hbm.xml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72056/discussion-between-arthur-khusntudinov-and-joe-taras).